# Resizing an LVM Storage Repository in XCP-ng

Tags: linux, lvm

So I have a server that had two hard drives (1tb each) in it on a simple raid 1. I then added two more drives and changed it to a raid 5. This increases the size from 1tb to (roughly) 2.6tb.

This server runs XCP-ng. So i logged into the terminal and went to parted and increased the size of the drive:

```
(parted) print free
Model: DELL PERC H730P Adp (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2879GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 5      1049kB  4296MB  4295MB  ext3
 2      4296MB  23.6GB  19.3GB
 1      23.6GB  43.0GB  19.3GB  ext3
 4      43.0GB  43.5GB  537MB   fat16                 boot
 6      43.5GB  44.6GB  1074MB  linux-swap(v1)
 3      44.6GB  2870GB  2825GB                        lvm
        2870GB  2879GB  8970MB  Free Space
```

You can see the lvm space is increased. But I'm struggling with the next step. Most of the online articles I've read say I need to create a new physical volume and add it to the volume group? (Which i thought I just extended the one that already existed in parted, maybe I'm wrong)

```
[13:44 tc-xcp-1 ~]# lsblk
NAME                                                                                                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
tde                                                                                                       254:4    0    64G  0 disk
tdc                                                                                                       254:2    0   124G  0 disk
tda                                                                                                       254:0    0   128G  0 disk
sda                                                                                                         8:0    0   2.6T  0 disk
├─sda4                                                                                                      8:4    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                                                                                                      8:2    0    18G  0 part
├─sda5                                                                                                      8:5    0     4G  0 part /var/log
├─sda3                                                                                                      8:3    0   2.6T  0 part
│ ├─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-VHD--9c6f01a9--1347--4032--8db7--30b7758db384 253:1    0 128.3G  0 lvm
│ ├─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-VHD--86427880--b447--4676--8876--fb0ed1282060 253:8    0  64.1G  0 lvm
│ ├─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-VHD--d70b89a4--63b8--4ec9--b0fb--6965f1344e91 253:6    0 108.2G  1 lvm
│ ├─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-VHD--b68400ad--4b79--4e87--b2ea--6045ef047bda 253:4    0 128.3G  0 lvm
│ ├─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-VHD--f2eaa5f0--4e48--46a3--9b3f--80da8ea12bbe 253:2    0  47.7G  1 lvm
│ ├─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-MGT                                           253:0    0     4M  0 lvm
│ ├─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-VHD--1191a142--7938--47cd--ae89--d9d33b89b597 253:7    0    10G  0 lvm
│ ├─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-VHD--ee89d390--27bd--4706--a310--fe9d5c4f2ed4 253:5    0 124.3G  0 lvm
│ └─VG_XenStorage--23503ed6--0b83--3737--3d77--5fe6051267b7-VHD--6d30b042--1952--4e1c--8d79--57ca90666ecc 253:3    0  44.8G  1 lvm
├─sda1                                                                                                      8:1    0    18G  0 part /
└─sda6                                                                                                      8:6    0     1G  0 part [SWAP]
tdd                                                                                                       254:3    0    10G  0 disk
tdb                                                                                                       254:1    0   128G  0 disk
```

Looks good, yeah? But then I go into XCP-ng and it doesn't see it. So I look further:

```
[13:45 tc-xcp-1 ~]# vgs
  VG                                                 #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  VG_XenStorage-23503ed6-0b83-3737-3d77-5fe6051267b7   1  13   0 wz--n- 852.23g 68.38g
[13:48 tc-xcp-1 ~]# pvs
  PV         VG                                                 Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  VG_XenStorage-23503ed6-0b83-3737-3d77-5fe6051267b7 lvm2 a--  852.23g 68.38g
```

I'm hoping at this point I've missed an obvious step and you guys can help me out because I am very confused. How do I get the volume group to recognize the rest of the space that is on it's drive?

UPDATE:
Figured out I needed to do a 'pvresize' command:

```
[13:52 tc-xcp-1 ~]# pvresize /dev/sda3
  Physical volume "/dev/sda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
[13:53 tc-xcp-1 ~]# vgs
  VG                                                 #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  VG_XenStorage-23503ed6-0b83-3737-3d77-5fe6051267b7   1  13   0 wz--n- <2.57t 1.80t
```

But the size of the new drive still isn't showing up in XCP-ng...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to use the `xe sr-scan` command.

So first:

```
[14:15 tc-xcp-1 ~]# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda3   VG VG_XenStorage-23503ed6-0b83-3737-3d77-5fe6051267b7   lvm2 [<2.57 TiB / 1.80 TiB free]
  Total: 1 [<2.57 TiB] / in use: 1 [<2.57 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

This tells me the uuid of my disk: it's the part after "VG_XenStorage-" (in this case: 23503ed6-0b83-3737-3d77-5fe6051267b7)

```
[14:17 tc-xcp-1 ~]# xe sr-scan uuid=23503ed6-0b83-3737-3d77-5fe6051267b7
```

All done, it shows up in XCP-ng now! yay!